# Do I need to patch the hole in my bathroom drywall behind the vanity?

Tags: drywall, caulking, vanity

I have a simple goal: I want to install a new vanity in my bathroom (in the United States, California specifically).

However, after extracting the prior vanity, I ended up having to cut some of the floor molding to accommodate for the size of the new vanity. Unfortunately, when I removed the piece of molding that I cut, I discovered it was hiding a 15cm wide, 4cm tall hole at the base of the drywall.
[image: Hole in the base of the drywall]

When I install the vanity, it will completely cover this hole. Assuming I mount the vanity right against the wall and caulk the joints, do I need to do any drywall repair to this hole or would I encounter any problems leaving it as-is?

Comment: I believe that fire codes require the wall to be closed, and drywall is a fire retardant. But I'll leave it to more knowledgeable members to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not even qualify as a hole as the back of the drywall is not broken. Just push some drywall mud, vinyl Spackle or caulking into it and call it good. you don't even need to make it pretty, just make sure it flush with the wall so it does not interfere with the vanity.